# Query seems to modify different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data from one table into another using the following query, but I am getting an error that is confusing me.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO [BILLING].[dbo].[Consolidated_Billing]
    ([Total Charge])
SELECT SUM(bt.[Service_Cost])
FROM [BILLING].[dbo].[Billing_Table] bt, [BILLING].[dbo].[Consolidated_Billing] cb
WHERE bt.NAME = cb.[Server Name]
AND bt.COST_CENTER = cb.[Cost Center]
AND bt.REMEDY_DIVISION = cb.Division;
```

**Error**

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Cannot inset the value NULL into column 'Hosting WS DEV', Table 'BILLING.dbo.Consolidated_Billing'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

While that is all jolly good (after all, the column 'Hosting WS DEV' is set to NOT NULL), I am wondering why the insert statement is even affecting that column at all? Shouldn't it only be inserting values into the [Total Charge] column (which is nullable)?

**Question**

Why is my `INSERT` affecting other columns? And how do I fix the error?

**Notes**

I do not have much experience with SQL, so there may be actions happening behind the scenes that I am not aware of. I did try modifying the query to change the `SELECT` to

`SELECT IIF(SUM(bt.[Service_Cost]) IS NULL, 0, SUM(bt.[Service_Cost]))`

But the same error still exists. I also tried using `LEFT JOIN` & `RIGHT JOIN` to no avail.

**EDIT**

As requested, here's the table schema. It's a bit of a doozy.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Consolidated_Billing](
    [Server Name] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [Cost Center] [nvarchar](13) NULL,
    [Division] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [Billing Comments] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Month] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Year] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Hosting WS DEV] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Hosting A] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Hosting DEV] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Solaris Std] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Virt Large Tier] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DS-Backup Tape Rec] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DR - Enhanced 12hr] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Wintel-2Way] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Hosting Websphere] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-AIX Std] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Solaris Mid] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Dr - Enhanced 4hr] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DR-IBM Rec Storage] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Citrix Server] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Linux Virtual] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Virt Med Tier] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Virt Dedicated] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Virt Small Tier] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DS-High Perform SAN] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DR - Enhanced SAN] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Wintel Physical] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Virt Split] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DR-Level 1 Wintel] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-DB Support] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Complex-Data Inf] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Wintel Virtual] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Unix/Linux Phy] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Hosting B] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-AIX Mid] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AppSerSup-Wintel-4Way] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DS-Standard SAN] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Total Charge] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Do you have a calculated column in there? It would be good to see the schema of Consolidated_Billing.

Comment: @RichBenner  Is there an easy way to get a table schema & include it in SO? And no, there aren't any explicitly calculated columns, but a lot of them were created using the `PIVOT` function.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it was a different table. do you have calculated columns in there?

Comment: @RichBenner see edited comment.

Comment: You can't `insert` a subset of the columns in a table. When you insert, you always `insert` complete rows of data. You may be able to not specify the values for selected columns, but then they are still inserted, either with default values (if a default has been defined in the table schema) or with NULL.

Comment: if you only insert [Total Charge] all other columns in the table will be set to default if they have any otherwise they will be null.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the query. Your query inserts a new *row* but only specifies values for a single column. The rest will get default values or NULL.

Comment: for your table schema, just right click on the table -> Script Table As -> Create To -> New Query Editor Window

Comment: I think I see the primary issue with inserting rows and why there is an error. So that answers my question with that. But it develops another: I just want to add data to the `[Total Charge]` column because every other column has data ( the total charge was added after the creation of the table). Is it possible at all to do that? From Mark, I will try an Update!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't insert "just in one column"; you insert a row into a table.  In the row you insert, every column of that table gets a value.

For columns you specify in the insert statement, they get the values you specify.  The rest get defaults defined for the table, or NULL if there is no default specified.  So if you don't give a value for a column, and it doesn't have a default, and it's a NOT NULL column, the insert fails.

**UPDATE**

From comments, it seems what you really want is an update statement

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET col1 = val1
```

would change the value of `col1` for every row in `myTable`; which, since it sounds like you must be dealing with a table where you intend there to be a single row, may do what you need.

If the table has many rows and you only mean to affect one of them, something like

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET col1 = val1
 WHERE col2 = val2
```

will only change `col1` for records with a particular value in `col2`, for example.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding, if I do not specify other columns the table will null out/defualt the existing values? Nope I think I get it

Comment: So is there any way to just update values for that one column without inserting new rows? All the other columns have data required.

Comment: To your first comment - no.  Insert creates a NEW row in the table.  It does not affect existing values.  It sounds like you want an UPDATE statement instead, to change a single value in an existing row.

Comment: Duh! Yes, I think update is what I want. I will try modifying my query to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The query is *not* affecting other columns. When you insert a new row though, columns that aren't explicitly specified will be initialized to their default values, or NULL if they have no defaults.

Non-nullable columns that have no defaults must be specified explicitly. This holds for all products that use SQL, not just a specific edition of SQL Server.

In your case, it seems that `[Hosting WS DEV]` is a non-nullable column without any defaults. You'll have to include it in your INSERT statement and add some value to it, eg:

```
INSERT INTO [BILLING].[dbo].[Consolidated_Billing]
    ([Total Charge], [Hosting WS DEV])
SELECT SUM(bt.[Service_Cost],'')
FROM [BILLING].[dbo].[Billing_Table] bt, [BILLING].[dbo].[Consolidated_Billing] cb
WHERE bt.NAME = cb.[Server Name]
AND bt.COST_CENTER = cb.[Cost Center]
AND bt.REMEDY_DIVISION = cb.Division;
```